# How to have a colspan with gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, html-table

I'm trying to make a grid view with asp.net. I want that columns' headers have a colspan like that :

[image]

But for the moment I have :

[image]

My code is :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GV" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnPreRender="gridView_PreRender">

            <Columns>

                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Num OF" DataField="cod_wo" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Num Seq" DataField="dat_sequence" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Article" DataField="article"/>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Qté OF Prévue" DataField="wo_qty" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Qté OF Revue" DataField="qty_revue" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Composant" DataField="composant" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Restant à assigner" DataField="restant_a_assigner" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Assignation HU" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Qté totale" DataField="qte_totale_assignee" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Num HU" DataField="num_hu" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Qté" DataField="qte_assignee" />

            </Columns>

        </asp:GridView>
```

and in code behind C# i have :

```
public static void MergeColumns(GridView gridView)
        {
            gridView.HeaderRow.Cells[0].RowSpan = 2;
            gridView.HeaderRow.Cells[1].RowSpan = 2;
            gridView.HeaderRow.Cells[2].RowSpan = 2;
            gridView.HeaderRow.Cells[3].RowSpan = 2;
            gridView.HeaderRow.Cells[4].RowSpan = 2;
            gridView.HeaderRow.Cells[5].RowSpan = 2;
            gridView.HeaderRow.Cells[6].RowSpan = 2;
            gridView.HeaderRow.Cells[7].RowSpan = 2;

            gridView.HeaderRow.Cells[8].ColumnSpan = 3;

        }
```

Do you have an idea ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do by using **RowCreated** event of grid view.For better understanding follow [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936417/colspan-gridview-rows)

Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure but if I have a good understanding, this sample concerne cells in the tab and not headers ?